# Multiple Alignments in equations

Tags: align, alignat

I want to align the equations like this 
[image]

but all I can get is this
[image]

And this is my code:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\mathcal{F}^N(t) \subset &&\sigma \{Q_0^N(0), \hat{Q}_1^N(0),     \hat{Q}_2^N(0)\} \vee \sigma \{A^N(s), 0 \leq s \leq t\}\\
&    &&\vee \sigma\{S_{12}^l(s),S_{20}^l,0 \leq s \leq t, l \geq 1\}\\
&    &&\vee \mathcal{N},\\
&(Q_0^N(0), \hat{Q}_1^N(0),\hat{Q}_2^N(0)), && \\
&A^N, && \\
&S_{12}^l, S_{20}^l, l \geq 1 && 
\end{alignat*}
```

I want to make the `\mathcal{F}^N(t)` and the following `Q_0^N(0), A^N,S_{12}^l` to be in the middle, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm sure there are other questions like this, but it's easier just to answer with an example.

since all lines after the first three are flush left, forget the "internal" `&&` separators, and use an `aligned` sub-element.  at that point, you may
as well use a simple `align*` rather than `alignat*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\begin{aligned}
  \mathcal{F}^N(t) \subset {} &\sigma \{Q_0^N(0), \hat{Q}_1^N(0),
        \hat{Q}_2^N(0)\} \vee \sigma \{A^N(s), 0 \leq s \leq t\}\\
    &\vee \sigma\{S_{12}^l(s),S_{20}^l,0 \leq s \leq t, l \geq 1\}\\
    &\vee \mathcal{N},
 \end{aligned}\\
&(Q_0^N(0), \hat{Q}_1^N(0),\hat{Q}_2^N(0)), \\
&A^N, \\
&S_{12}^l, S_{20}^l, l \geq 1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `aligned` environment to put some aligned equations inside another displaymath environment. Thus, in this case, you can use an `align*` environment for the left-alignment, and an `aligned` environment inside that for the first few lines, which acts like one line for the purposes of the outer `align*` environment.

```
\begin{align*}
&
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{F}^N(t) \subset &\sigma \{Q_0^N(0), \hat{Q}_1^N(0), \hat{Q}_2^N(0)\} \vee \sigma \{A^N(s), 0 \leq s \leq t\}\\
    &\vee \sigma\{S_{12}^l(s),S_{20}^l,0 \leq s \leq t, l \geq 1\}\\
    &\vee \mathcal{N},
\end{aligned}\\
&(Q_0^N(0), \hat{Q}_1^N(0),\hat{Q}_2^N(0)),\\
&A^N,\\
&S_{12}^l, S_{20}^l, l \geq 1
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: the `\subset` in the first line really needs to be followed by `{}` to get the correct spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions, one using the `\mathrlap` command, from `mathtools`, the other with a plain `align*` environment and an `array`. Also replaced `\hat` with `widehat`, which fits better the size of  uppercase Q:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\mathcal{F}^N(t) \subset {}&&\sigma \{Q_0^N(0), \widehat{Q}_1^N(0), \widehat{Q}_2^N(0)\} \vee \sigma \{A^N(s), 0 \leq s \leq t\}\\
& &&\vee \sigma\{S_{12}^l(s),S_{20}^l,0 \leq s \leq t, l \geq 1\}\\
& &&\vee \mathcal{N},\\
&\mathrlap{(Q_0^N(0), \widehat{Q}_1^N(0),\widehat{Q}_2^N(0)),} && \\
&A^N, && \\
&\mathrlap{S_{12}^l, S_{20}^l, l \geq 1 }
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
&\mathcal{F}^N(t) \subset {}\begin{array}[t]{@{}l}\sigma \{Q_0^N(0), \widehat{Q}_1^N(0), \widehat{Q}_2^N(0)\} \vee \sigma \{A^N(s), 0 \leq s \leq t\}\\
\vee \sigma\{S_{12}^l(s),S_{20}^l,0 \leq s \leq t, l \geq 1\}\\
\vee \mathcal{N},
\end{array}\\
& (Q_0^N(0), \widehat{Q}_1^N(0),\widehat{Q}_2^N(0)),\\
& A^N, \\
& S_{12}^l, S_{20}^l, l \geq 1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]